# How to change ie browser as Quirks mode?

Tags: cross-browser

How to change the ie browser mode as Quirks mode and what is Quirks mode?

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer press `F12` and then change the document mode. Alternatively in IE you can press `Alt Q.`

Quirks mode is to allow you to develop for older browsers, i.e. I.E 6. Mainly for backwards compatibility.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Comment: we can change the mode, using any client script(jquery)?

Comment: not having a doctype will turn the browser in to quirks mode too (not recommended)

Comment: @user304018 - I would not force the clients browser into quirks. You should be developing for new web standards and gracefully degrading code that supports older browsers.

Comment: @DarrenDavies - yae that i know, but i want to use it for a particular page only becoz there i'm using one third party control web combo(older version, temp im use this), its support only below ie 8 version.